# Django Query Get Related Set Count

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am querying the db and am trying to find the count of a related set named 'item'.

```
user_lists = List.objects.filter(user=user).select_related('city','city__country')
```

that brings up the items I want, but to add the count of the related set, I'm adding annotate:

```
user_lists = List.objects.filter(user=user).select_related('city','city__country').annotate(item_count=Count('item'))
```

However, this returns an empty query from the db. Any ideas why?  I'm not getting any errors. Just an empty query set.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer, just an idea on how you can investigate: check the actual query, that's being executes via`print str(some_queryset.query)`. Then you could try executing the query in `manage.py dbshell` and check the results.

Also posting your models and db engine might be useful, as it might be related.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use count() method to count items in a QuerySet: 
[count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count)

```
user_lists_count = List.objects.filter(user=user).select_related('city','city__country').count()
```

is this working ?

hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized it was an issue with the `item_count` variable. When I used `total_items` it worked fine.